# My landlord verbally told me that they have a secert setup of cameras, what should I do?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property

I was discussing something with LL and in heat of moment he verbally said that he have a secert setup of cameras.

He wasn't explicit if it's inside building or outside, but he said that he knows how many people live in the building.

What should I do ?

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: Use your eyes to look for cameras, and add details to your question here if you think one location violates your rights.

Comment: Do you have more people living there than you told him?

Comment: @Putvi no, never

Comment: @bobuhito I will have another look now, if there arn't any, where do I stand

Comment: Well he's obviously trying to scare you then.

Comment: @Putvi That is what I am hoping as well, but I just want to know in case he isn't even if there is 0.01%, Can I at least report him to authorities, so if something comes up in future, I have at least a reference regarding this. It's not an easy thing to disregard, specially that LL has keys to house and what at some point they did something dodgy

Comment: He shouldn't have them inside your living space, but if he has them outside there isn't much you can really do.